# ng : ui-switch is not a known element in angular5?

Tags: angular, angular5, uiswitch

I'm trying to work with ui-switch as in this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-ui-switch) but i'm fascing an error :

```
ng : ui-switch is not a known element  
ng : if ui-switch is An angular component then verify it's a part of this 
     module
```

To install ui-switch i used this command in Angular CLI :

```
npm install ngx-ui-switch@^1.6.0 --save
```

In my project.module.ts :

```
import { UiSwitchModule } from 'ngx-ui-switch';
import {ProjectsComponent} from './projects/projects.component';
import {NewProjectsComponent} from './new-projects/new-projects.component';
import { EditProjectComponent } from './projects/edit-project/edit- 
        project.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [FormsModule,
            CommonModule,UiSwitchModule ,ProjetRoutingModule],

  declarations: [ProjectsComponent,
          NewProjectsComponent,
          EditProjectComponent]
 })
```

In project.component.html i wrote :

```
 <ui-switch></ui-switch>
```

Any idea ?

Ps : i'm using angular 5

**EDIT**

This is the structure :

[image]

Comment: In which component are you trying to use `<ui-switch>`? Are you using in in `AppComponent` or some other component?

Comment: Perhaps you should re-read the docs on the link you cite. You are trying to use the wrong version of the library.

Comment: Which module is `project.component` a part of? I can't see it in the `declarations` of this module

Comment: I have a directory called project , inside i have project.module.ts and  the component project.component.ts .html .css ,

Comment: @AamirKhan : i have edited the post with the structure of the project

Comment: @R.Richards Ah okey i'll read it again and see

Comment: Are you sure the above NgModule snippet is from project.module? Why do you have the AppComponent declared Ina feature module and not the app.module?

Comment: It may be that you are missing `bootstrap: [ProjectComponent]` in project.module.ts. (based on the standard app.module created with angular-cli)

Comment: @RichardMatsen : That was the reason , thank you so much for help , but can you please explain to me why adding this fixed the problem ? and also i'll accept your answer if you post your solution that helped me :)

Comment: Glad to help. I just noticed your project structure was a little different to the 'standard' and tried it with [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/), then noticed the difference in the base module.

Comment: That was really helpful :) thank you again bro

Answer (score 0):

You are using `1.6.0` which is targeted for angular v4 as stated in the [github readme doc](https://github.com/webcat12345/ngx-ui-switch). Due to angular 4 uses a different metadata version for decorators.

> Beyond Angular v4
>   The master branch will contain the latest code for the latest version of Angular. When upgrading this library to a new version of Angular, a new x.y-stable branch will be created to allow bugfixes. Below is how to install the latest version of the library.

This is what you want to do:

```
npm install ngx-ui-switch --save
# yarn add ngx-ui-switch
```

Comment: Thank you for answering , it's resolved now , the problem was that i was missing missing bootstrap: [ProjectComponent] in project.module.ts.

Comment: BTW I don't think it is correct, as ngx-ui-switch 1.6.0 did work with Angular 5.

Comment: In fact i don't know but as first solution i uninstalled v1.6.0 and used npm install ngx-ui-switch --save instead .